# After post request display message is not working

Tags: php, javascript

I am sending post request on php and after post i want to show thank you message 
my post code is:

```
<?php
    $error = '';
    $FullName = $_POST['FullName'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    $Content = $FullName." ".$Email." ".$Password;
    $server= '192.168.1.13:3033';
    $path = '/user/registration';

    $headers= "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nHost: $server\r\nContent-length: $Content\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen($server, $port);

    if (!$fp) return false;

    fputs($fp, $headers);
    fputs($fp, $Content);

    $ret = "";

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $ret.= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    print $ret;
?>
```

my post request is working but i do not how to display message on the same page 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You wish to display the error on the form page? Set the form to submit to the same file, check if it was submitted and run the code above and echo the text you wish.

Comment: not an error massage.. form successfully register thankyou message on the same form

Comment: Try `echo "Thank you etc....";` after `print $ret;` or after `fputs($fp, $Content);`

Comment: Yeah, I meant success message sorry, still the same principle though.

Comment: Or you can try to var_dump($ret) and see what's its value.

Comment: var_dump($ret), how this show message???

Comment: only echo command is not working after print $ret; statement.

Comment: @ana Then try `die("Thank you");` after `fclose($fp);`

Comment: @ana How are you defining `$port`? I don't see it anywhere else in your form. Theoretically, your form will **fail** without it.

Comment: die also not working..

Comment: @ana That's because your form is **failing** because you haven't defined `$port`. What values are given to `$port`? My answer: there is none, not that I can see in your **posted** code. All I see is `$fp = fsockopen($server, $port);`, that's it. `$server` is defined `$server= '192.168.1.13:3033';` but not `$port`.

Comment: The port is define because to listen on all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but you could give a try to the following and let me know

```
<?php

$port = 3033;
$error = '';
$FullName = $_POST['FullName'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
$Content = $FullName." ".$Email." ".$Password;
$server= '192.168.1.13';
$path = '/user/registration';

$headers = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nHost: $server\r\nContent-length: $Content\r\n\r\n";
$data = $headers . $Content;
$fp = fsockopen($server, $port);

if (!$fp)
{ 
    return false;
}
else
{

    fputs($fp, $data);

    $ret = "";

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $ret.= fgets($fp, 1024);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    print("Thank you for using our service.\r\n\r\n".$ret);        
}


?>
```

Comment: This stands to also **fail**, because you haven't defined or passed a value for `$port`.

Comment: I assume that $port is defined, without $port it will fail for sure ofc

Comment: The OP didn't post it ($port value) and expects you and I, and others to **magically** assume it has been defined.

Comment: @ana like the rest of the variables you have assigned already $port = 333 if 333 is the port you need right before $error = '';

Comment: @ana You should know that, after all you built the form. Where did you get your code from? If you didn't build it and got it from another source and didn't get one that was **fully tested**, then you're wasting your time as well as ours.

Comment: @ana From what I noticed in your `$server` variable, your port is `3033`.

Comment: +1 for that 'ASS out of U and ME' @ana I updated the code but Fred is right

Comment: ok actually my port is 3033 but i already define in $server so actually i am removing it from code..

Comment: @ana Here, I found a link related to port settings, you can Google that subject too, see: http://www.functionblog.com/?p=67=1 - Theoretically, you could set `$port=3033;` but then you need to see the info in the page link I included here.

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas It's an old expression which I rarely use, but in this case, it was **perfect**. ;-) cheers

Comment: @ana You can always remove `$port` from `$fp = fsockopen($server, $port);` and set it as `$fp = fsockopen($server);` but then you might get an error message that it needs 2 parameters.

Comment: @ana **Here**, consult the PHP manual on `fsockopen`. It shows an example where you could set the port, rather than its default of **80**. For example `$fp = fsockopen("udp://127.0.0.1", 13, $errno, $errstr);` **13** is the port which you can change to **3033**. Consult:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php for more information on the subject.

Answer (score -1):

The [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) function might be of interest here.

Comment: @ana If you mix `echo` with `headers`, it will give you an error. Thefore you have to put it outside of that.

Comment: "Through some kind of alert" .. what do you mean here? Is this page meant to return information to an Ajax call, or is the user taken to this page when they submit the form?

Comment: yes exactly after posting all the value .. i want to show successful register message..

Comment: **Theoretically**, your answer was good and I don't know why it was (**-1**). Whoever minused you, should take it back. *You didn't know* and fell into a **trap**, sad to say. **Food for thought:** Next time, make it as a **comment**. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Fred - I'm still a bit new to SO in the posting regard. Lesson learned, regardless.

Comment: @Seiyria You're welcome and you'll get "the hang of it". I was there too, at one time. Cheers (**P.S.**: I rarely make the same mistake twice) ;-)